# How to redirect to a php file on subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have my app running from the sub folder within the main domain.

/html - main folder ( has wordpress installed and running )
/html/orm - my app

orm folder contains multiple sub folders like profile, usermanager with php files in it.

so user dashboard will be /orm/profile/dashboard ( dashboard is a php file - dashboard.php )

I have a php that redirects the request to different php files in separate folders which works with htaccess redirect on localhost (xampp), but it's not redirecting on the server, which has wordpress running in the main folder.

I tried this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ app-redir.php [QSA,L]
```

and this

```
RewriteBase /orm/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$ /orm/app-redir.php [L]
```

none of them redirects, though it works fine on localhost on xampp, I am not able to figure out and I get this error - "The requested URL was not found on this server" regardless of what I try.

Comment: WordPress' URL rewriting will rewrite every request that doesn't match a physically existing file or folder, to it's own index.php. You need to add an exception to the WP rewriting first of all, so that it lets all requests for /orm/ pass through unchanged.